# Using gnuplot for files with variable names included

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file that is set up as follows:

```
varName1= 1   varName2= 3
varName1= 3   varName2= 4
# and so on
```

Is there a `gnuplot` command that ignores the variable names? 
I just need to plot the numbers.

I can't simply do:

```
plot "fileName.dat" linenumber
```

because the variable names are included.

Comment: Would you know what version of gnuplot you are using? For example when you start gnuplot, it displays the version, what does it say on yours. Also, if that is what your current data looks like and the exact command used, can you post a screenshot of the current result? The one that includes the unwanted variable names. Hope to see how exactly it renders, may give clues how to fix. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In these cases I would suggest to use an external parser like `awk` or `sed`.

In your case this should work:

```
plot "< awk '{print $2 $3}' test.txt" w l
```

Answer (score 1):

gnuplot will regard the variable names in your file just as another column. Simply `plot fname using 2:4` will work in your example.

If you don't always have the space after "=", you can do `set datafile separator '= '`. (This sets " " and "=" as independend separators, not "= ".)